# Why do I get error: Error: <identifier> expected in line 9 am I missing a import

Tags: java

Following is my code and I have put comments to explain what am I facing.

Should I be importing something else? I'm using the `jGrasp` compiler?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.lang.*;
/*this is just a test class to learn how to use substring. I was trying to use substring 
   to play around with strings in this case my dogs name. I was doing exercises on codingbat.com
  and came across the substring method. 
*/
public class Donna extends Applet {

    String DogName = "Donna Peluda";       // declare the String variable DogName
    String FirstDog = "";                  // declare FirstDog String variable blank
    FirstDog = DogName.substring( 0, 2);   // I get "Donna.java:9: error: <identifier> expected" 
    // if I comment out line 9 it prints "Donna Peluda" ok
    // Ive tried examples from the web and get the same error and spent 2 evenings on this so 

    public void paint(Graphics d) {
        d.drawString(DogName + FirstDog ,25, 25);//print the result to the applet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not the right place for assigning.
If you really want to do that at there, try this

```
public class Donna extends Applet
{
    String dogName = "Donna Peluda";
    String FirstDog = "";
    {
        FirstDog = DogName.substring(0, 2);
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 2):

The class body (everything between the first open bracket and the last closing bracket) is only allowed to contain the following artifacts:

```
class MyClass extends MySuperClass implements YourInterface {
    // field, constructor, and
    // method declarations
}
```

The line

```
FirstDog = DogName.substring( 0, 2);
```

is not allowed in the field declaration section. You can move that line into the constructor. Or just initialize the field directly:

```
String FirstDog = DogName.substring( 0, 2);
```

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html for a detailed reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String DogName = "Donna Peluda";
String FirstDog = getFirst();

public String getFirst()
{
    return DogName.substring( 0, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Because jvm can not ensure the invocation order of this three declaration when init Donna.

```
String DogName = "Donna Peluda";     
String FirstDog = "";
FirstDog = DogName.substring( 0, 2);
```

But `{}` can be invoked after class member assignment, so:

```
String DogName = "Donna Peluda";
String FirstDog = "";
{             
    FirstDog = DogName.substring(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `pubic` isn't a valid Java access modifier.

Comment: instance method can be invoked by class member's declaration if that method does not refer to that class member. just try:    String str1 = getStr();
    
    public String getStr(){
        return this.str;
    }